# WP8 - Automatically open keyboard on &123 option

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, keyboard

while developing a new Windows Phone 8 software, I got stuck with this issue.

I'd need to open the keyboard straight to this view:

[image]

But all I can do is this (just giving focus to a text-box, that's easy enough!):

[image: https://imageshack.com/i/0ytaa6j]

Comment: do you need only numbers?

Comment: Nope, I need the "full" keyboard as showed above, if possible.

Comment: Not possible, If my knowledge serves me correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link for allowed scopes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28VS.96%29.aspx

I believe the view you are after is called "Numeric Mode"; This following link has some images as well.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1706099&seqNum=2

Answer (score 1):

Set the TextBox InputScope properties to Digits in your xaml code

```
<TextBox InputScope="Digits " Name="txtNumbers" />
```

and your code behind page use below line of code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       txtNumbers.Focus();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompts answer, but I don't just need digits, I need the "full" keyboard as showed above, if possible.

Comment: @guido1993 Ok than remove InpoutScope Property from TextBox.